# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent primary key as a multiple key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a model that has the following columns:

- blog_id (fillabale)
- date (fillable)
- counter

Unique key on blog_id + date

whenever I'm trying to get results from this table by using, for instance,

```
$model = BlogCounter::findOrNew(2,'2016-09-25');
```

Or

```
$model = BlogCounter::whereBlogId(2)->whereDate('date','=','2016-09-25')->first()
```

I'm getting error:

> column blog_counter.id does not exist

I tried to override primaryKey and set it to 
null / ['blog_id', 'date'] / 'blog_id,date' 
none of the above solved this problem of Eloquent trying to fetch raw by id..

I don't have primary key on this table because I'm using unique key instead.

Am I missing something? How do I enforce Eloquent models to work without a primary key?

BTY, I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5 at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't because laravel provides find method on only key attributes of the eloquent model. So you have to make a primary key field. See this https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

Comment: The error you posted is returned by the first query using findOrNew, what's the error you're getting with the second query that uses wheres/first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent assumes that there is an **id** column in your table that identifies a row. In your case this column is named **blog_id** so you need to let Eloquent know.

You can do that by defining **primaryKey** attribute in your model. It doesn't need to be the primary key in the database as long as it can be used to fetch a single record:

```
class BlogCounter extends Model {
  protected $primaryKey = 'blog_id';
}
```

Comment: @edrzej.kurylo  my "key" is a combination of 2 fields (unique)
date + blog_id..
This is what I'm struggling with..

Comment: Eloquent doesn't support composite keys, so you can't use find*() methods to fetch records. You'll need to add your own logic to your model